# Measurement inconsistency in Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am using Qiskit in an algorithm. In the end, I am measuring exactly a register of 4 qubits but the histograms show states with 5 qubits.

This is the code I used:

```
qwc = QuantumCircuit(qnodes, qnodes2, cqnodes, cqnodes2)
qwc.measure(qnodes, cnodes)
qwc.draw(output="mpl")
```

and finally `qnodes2` is measured and represented in the plot as states qubits?

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Thanks for the question. Could you post some code so that I could reproduce the problem?

Comment: `qwc = QuantumCircuit(qnodes, qnodes2, cqnodes, cqnodes2)` And then `qwc.measure(qnodes, cnodes)` and then `qwc.draw(output="mpl")` finally i get qnodes2 measured and represented in the plot as states qubits

Comment: Thanks for the code. However, I'm still unsure exactly how large these registers are, and how you call execute. So I've not been able to reproduce it.

Comment: `qnodes` 4 and `qnodes2` just 1
execution is like : `qwc = runQWC(qwc)`

Comment: You measured in `cnodes` but the circuit includes `cqnodes` and `cqnodes2`...